# Create a dash graph with dropdown menu

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Hi I have an excel file that looks like this where there are three diferent servers (A, B, C).

[image]

I am trying to build a dash app that has a dropdown menu which will make it possible to select the desired server and display the graph for CPU Usage and Memory Usage for each server.

I have tried to modify the following code from the official Dash website. Data can be found on https://plotly.github.io/datasets/country_indicators.csv

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

df = pd.read_csv('https://plotly.github.io/datasets/country_indicators.csv')

available_indicators = df['Indicator Name'].unique()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='xaxis-column',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value='Fertility rate, total (births per woman)'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='xaxis-type',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Linear', 'Log']],
                value='Linear',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='yaxis-column',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value='Life expectancy at birth, total (years)'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='yaxis-type',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Linear', 'Log']],
                value='Linear',
                labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
            )
        ],style={'width': '48%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'})
    ]),

    dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic'),

    dcc.Slider(
        id='year--slider',
        min=df['Year'].min(),
        max=df['Year'].max(),
        value=df['Year'].max(),
        marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df['Year'].unique()},
        step=None
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('indicator-graphic', 'figure'),
    [Input('xaxis-column', 'value'),
     Input('yaxis-column', 'value'),
     Input('xaxis-type', 'value'),
     Input('yaxis-type', 'value'),
     Input('year--slider', 'value')])
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,
                 xaxis_type, yaxis_type,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df['Year'] == year_value]

    return {
        'data': [dict(
            x=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == xaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            y=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Value'],
            text=dff[dff['Indicator Name'] == yaxis_column_name]['Country Name'],
            mode='markers',
            marker={
                'size': 15,
                'opacity': 0.5,
                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
            }
        )],
        'layout': dict(
            xaxis={
                'title': xaxis_column_name,
                'type': 'linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log'
            },
            yaxis={
                'title': yaxis_column_name,
                'type': 'linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log'
            },
            margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 0},
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The ouput of this code gives an output similar to mine except that the second drop down menu and the slicer would not be needed
[image]
I am struggling to understand how to modify the code to be able to apply to mine. Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your callback func will have a single `Output` and a single `Input`. The output will be the `figure` of the graph, and the input will be the `value` of the dropdown.

In your callback, you can filter the dataframe you build from the Excel file something like this:

```py
df = pandas.read_excel('path/to/my/file.xlsx')
df = df[df['server'].eq(dropdown_value)]
```

From there just fit the data into the `dict` that represents the `figure` much like it's done in the Dash example and `return` it.