# Plotly interactive visualizations dropdown

Tags: python, plotly, python-interactive

I am attempting to create a plotly dash drop-down whose selection is used to filter a dataframe and generate a pie chart from the filtered dataframe. I started with the working code from [plotly interactive visualizations documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing) and as carefully as possible went through and deleted all the extra. (all I want is one drop-down and one output graph as per [similar stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759334/create-a-dash-graph-with-dropdown-menu)).

For now I will stick with the first question that has come to mind relating to the logic of the `@app.callback` section of the code.

```
@app.callback(
Output('indicator-graphic', 'figure'),
[Input('choose_species', 'value')])
```

The input tag makes sense, as there is a dropdown above with `id` and `value` equal to the arguments of `Input`:

```
html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='choose_species',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
            value='Pacific Water Shrew'
        )
```

However, while the out put has a related `id`:

```
dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic')
```

there is nothing else in the code with the text `figure` which I would assume would have to come from the output of a function `update_graph` as it is called in the example code. There is no other mention of figure in my own code (which doesnt work obviously) nor in the example code (which does work to my surprise, given that I can't figure out how).

**Question:**

Given the above, how do I tie by `@app_callback` to my `update-graph` function. Please keep in mind I am quite new to all coding languages involved.

Comment: maybe first assing function and use `print()` to see if it work - `figure` doesn't have to be visible in Graph arguments but it may have this variable (as class variable which is created automatically).

Comment: simply put `def update_graph(argument): ... code...` directly below `@app.callback()` - `@` means it is decoreator and it will get first function below and use it.

Comment: Please refer to the SO for the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042682/plotly-dash-update-graph-with-dropdown-input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience you can do something like below:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])

app.layout = html.Div([html.H5('Drop Down',className='text-center'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
            id='choose_species',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
                value='Pacific Water Shrew',
                multi=True,
                disabled=False,
                clearable=True,
                searchable=True),
            dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic',figure={},style={'height':300,'width':'auto'})
])

@app.callback(Output('indicator-graphic', 'figure'),
             [Input('choose_species', 'value')])

def build_graph(species): 
    fig = px.line(df,x='',y='',color='')
    return fig

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False
```

)

You need to add `dcc.Graph` and `figure={}` in your layout, and under `@app.callback` you have to add a function to return `figure` after filtering by `dropdown`.

Comment: ahah! it is running! just had to change the input of the `build_graph` to be `value` instead of `species` and the output of the same funciton to be `figure` to match the layout and callback sections. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`figure` is part of `Graph` and you can assing value to `figure` at start - like this

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure={
                  'data': [{
                        'x': [1,2,3],
                        'y': [1,7,4],
                  }],
              }
    ),
])        

app.run_server()
```

but you can also define `Graph` with empty `figure`

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(),
])        

app.run_server()
```

and you may later try to assign some values to `figure`.

And this is what code with `callback` is doing.

It uses `id` to access `Graph` and it assigns to `figure` value returned from `callback`.

When page is loaded then it creates `Dropdown` (with `id='choose_species'`) and it assigns `'Pacific Water Shrew'` to `value` and this executes `callback` with `[Input('choose_species', 'value')]` which returns dictionary and callback assigns it to `figure` in `Graph` with `id='indicator-graphic'`

---

`@` in `@app.callback` means it is decorator and you have to put your function directly below decorat to assign it to this decorator - or rather to execute this decorator with this function as argument.

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc, Output, Input

# --- data ---

my_data = {
    'Hello': {'x':[1,2,3], 'y': [1,7,4]},
    'World': {'x':[1,2,3], 'y': [7,1,4]},
    'Pacific Water Shrew': {'x':[1,2,3], 'y': [7,4,1]}
}

available_indicators = list(my_data.keys())

# --- HTML ---

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='choose_species',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in available_indicators],
        value='Pacific Water Shrew'
    ),

    dcc.Graph(id='indicator-graphic'),
])        

# --- code ---

@app.callback(
Output('indicator-graphic', 'figure'),
[Input('choose_species', 'value')])
def update_graph(arg):
    print('value from dropdown:', arg)
    
    my_x = my_data[arg]['x']
    my_y = my_data[arg]['y']
    
    return {
        'data': [dict(
            x=my_x,
            y=my_y,
        )],
    }

app.run_server()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! This answer totally worked too! Roughly th same except I suppose that the `figure{}` argument is not necessary in the HTML section as you said.

Comment: I suppose I should compose a new question, but: I am tyring to embed this into an html document. I am assuming that this solution can mostly be directly written to the document with exception to the graph building function `update_graph` in this case, which would have to be in a python script which is referred to by the html? Sorry if this is completely ignorant as an assumption.

Comment: Ah nevermind. The `<iframe>` method worked for the time being.